# Uncaught TypeError: hook.apply is not a function on using onEnter in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Using Redux Thunk middleware, I am implementing the API call.

But in React Router when use `onEnter`, I've got issues.
[image]

And here is some of my codes:

-router.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute, Router } from 'react-router';

import Layout from './components/Layout';
import Landing from './components/Landing';
import Test from './components/test';
import { getCurrentUser } from './actions/user.actions';
import { fetchUser } from './actions/user.actions';

import requireAuth from './lib/requireAuth';
// import waitingForAuth from './lib/waitingForAuth';
import store from './store';

export default (
    <Router>
       <Route path="/" component={Layout} onEnter=
             {store.dispatch(getCurrentUser())}>
            <IndexRoute component={requireAuth(Landing)} />
       </Route>
       <Route path="/test" component={Layout} onEnter=
            {store.dispatch(fetchUser())}>
            <IndexRoute component={Test} />
         </Route>
    </Router>  
 );
```

-user.action.js

```
export function getCurrentUser() {
return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch({ type: 'USER_CURRENT_PENDING' });
    dispatch({
        type: 'USER_CURRENT_FULFILLED', payload: [{
            Name: 'username',
            Value: 'test@user.com'
        }, {
            Name: 'name',
            Value: 'Test'
        }, {
            Name: 'family_name',
            Value: 'User'
        }, {
            Name: 'email',
            Value: 'test@user.com'
        }, {
            Name: 'phone_number',
            Value: '555-11111'
        }]
    });
}
}

export const REQUEST = 'API_REQUEST';

function requestUser() {
    return {
      type: REQUEST
    }
}

 export const RECEIVE = 'API_RECEIVE';

 function receiveUser(user) {
     return {
         type: RECEIVE,
         payload: {
           user
         }
      }
   }

  export const FAILURE = 'API_FAILURE';

  function failureUser(message) {
      return {
           type: FAILURE,
           payload: {
               message 
            }
        }
   }

export function fetchUser() {
console.log('fetchUser');
return function (dispatch) {
  dispatch(requestUser())
  return fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1`)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status >= 400) {
        dispatch(failureUser("Bad response from server"));
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(user =>
      dispatch(receiveUser(user))
    );
}
}
```

-userReducer.js

```
 ...
 case 'API_RECEIVE':
  const userInfo = {
    userId: 0,
    id: 0,
    title: '',
    body: ''
  }
  action.payload.forEach(function (attribute) {
    switch (attribute.Name) {
      case 'userId':
        userInfo.userId = attribute.Value;
        break;
      case 'id':
        userInfo.id = attribute.Value;
        break;
      case 'title':
        userInfo.title = attribute.Value;
        break;
      case 'body':
        userInfo.body = attribute.Value;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }, this);
  return {
    ...state,
    loggedIn: true,
    loggingIn: false,
    userId: userInfo.userId,
    id: userInfo.id,
    title: userInfo.title,
    body: userInfo.body,
    loginRedirect: undefined,
    loginError: undefined
  }
default:
  return state;
 }
```

Help me!!!

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. **Don't post images of code or error messages.** Read [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
In order to fix this issue, I don't have to `return` in `action` like below:

```
export function fetchUser() {
console.log('fetchUser');
function (dispatch) {
  dispatch(requestUser())
  fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1`)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status >= 400) {
        dispatch(failureUser("Bad response from server"));
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(user =>
      dispatch(receiveUser(user))
    );
}
}
```